# Unknown class : EntityBareJid or Cannot resolve symbol JidCreate. issue on smack library 4.2.1

Tags: android, ejabberd

I am using smack 4.2.1 library on my app. I have fetch following issue

```
EntityBareJid jid = JidCreate.entityBareFrom("jid");
```

in my above code Unknown class EntityBareJid or cannot resolve symbol JidCreate. how to fixed it. is it smack version library issue?

Comment: download jxmpp jar file from https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=jxmpp and copy that into your libs folder then rebuild

Comment: Thank you @gaurang